# Adding inline many to many objects in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm fairly new to Django and having read the documentation on its relational models and inline admin forms ([docs on InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)) I'm struggling to figure out if the following is possible out of the box, or if I should roll my own forms.

Let's say I have two objects: Films and Directors, this is a many-to-many relationship as defined in in the model declarations as follows:

```
class Film(Model):
    director = ManyToManyField('Director')
```

Now in the detail form for a Film object I would like to *add* inline Director objects (they just have a name field as sole property). Not just selecting existing instances, but being able to *create new ones*, inline in the form of the Film object.

```
class DirectorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Director
    extra = 3


class FilmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (
        DirectorInline,
        )
```

This throws an error, because it expects a foreign key on the Director object. 
Is what I'm trying to achieve possible without creating a custom form, validator etc. ?
Any tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The default widget for Many-to-many field in admin or widgets with [`filter_vertical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical) or `filter_horizontal` property allows you to add new item. There is a green "+" sign near the field to open a popup window and add new Director instance.

But if you need the inline style admin you should reference to the [through-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). If you don't specify the custom model Django creates a simple model with 2 foreign keys to Director and Film.

So you can try to create inline like

```
class DirectorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Film.director.through
    extra = 3
```

This will not raise an exception and will generate an inline form, but you will have to select directors from drop-down list. I think you can overwrite this by using custom form.

Comment: Igor, (or anyone else), How would you add options to the inline such as fields?

Comment: @Greg I don't really understand what you try to achieve. If you want to save additional data to your M2M model, you can use custom through model - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany If you want just to add fields to admin panel, you can redefine ``DirectorInline.form``

Comment: @Igor How redefine Inline.form?

Comment: @mamasi - the same way you define the custom form for admin [**link**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) you can define the form for inline [**link**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form)

Comment: Is it possible to make the form for a new Inline instance inline? That is, without a pop-up?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to add a "+" button next to a ManyToManyField is to make sure that both objects are registered in your admin.py file. Otherwise Django won't create a form for the second type of object

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Film)
admin.site.register(Director)
```