# Creating Model Relationships Via Forms

Tags: django

What is the defacto way of creating model relationships in Django via frontend forms.
For example a user signs up for service using a form, they start a quote.
In getting a quote they can select and add products to their quote specifying variable such as sizes in this process.

This is modelled with relevant User, Quote, Product models and relevant relationships.

I am trying to work out the best way that these are linked together by frontend forms and views.

Would I load into the quote form a hidden field for the related user_id for example, which I can then process manually to form the one-to-many relationship.

I am just wondering if this is something accounted for within forms or if I have to manually create the forms to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the more complicated things to try and achieve but there are several things in Django which will help you.

You're going to need a [`ManyToMany` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) on the Quote model to link the Products to it.

This can be displayed in forms simply via a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield
... which is just renders a basic multiple select list of existing products.

The interface you want probably looks more like an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) however. The complication here is that they are designed for `ForeignKey` relations rather than `ManyToMany`.

Under the covers, a ManyToMany relation is actually just two ForeignKey relations, via an intermediate 'through' model. We can exploit this to build an inline formset on the through model, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10999074/202168

You'll note the caveat in that answer, the inline rows won't know which `Quote` they belong to unless you override some code.

You may like to look at some helper apps which provide custom widgets for ManyToMany fields:

- https://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/
- http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/